# How to access nested attributes or return a default value if any of the attributes doesn't exist?

Tags: python

In JavaScript (and Node.js and TS), when we have an object `A` which has an attribute `B`, which has an attribute `C`, which has an attribute `D` and so on, we may use it like that:

```js
const x = A?.B?.C?.D
```

Is there something similar in Python?
I want `x` to be `None` if any of `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D` is `None`. Actually, I need `x = A.B.C.D or DEFAULT_VALUE`

What I do today is very verbose:

```py
x = None
if A is not None and A.B is not None and A.B.C is not None:
    x = A.B.C.D
```

Is there a one-line solution in Python?

I prefer an approach like this, but it is still very verbose and I repeat myself. Looking for DRY.

```
x = A and A.B and A.B.C and A.B.C.D or DEFAULT_VALUE
```

Comment: Maybe `try: x = A.B.C.D except: x = None` (not one-line)?

Comment: @Costin Did you find any of the provided answers acceptable? If so, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: @simon None of the answers is what I was expecting. But they say that what I'm looking for doesn't exist. So, I have to reset my expectations and accept the best compromise. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably no such concise solution in Python. The most "pythonic" way would probably be to "ask for forgiveness rather than permission" (see the ["EAFP" entry in the Python Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP)), i.e. to use a try-except statement that directly tries to access `D` (no need for intermediate checks) and that fails gracefully by providing the required `DEFAULT_VALUE` in the error case:

```py
DEFAULT_VALUE = ...  # TODO: Provide default

try:
    x = A.B.C.D
except (NameError, AttributeError):
    x = DEFAULT_VALUE
```

You only need the `NameError` for the case that `A` might not exist at all. If you are sure that `A` exists (i.e. `A` has been defined and holds any value including None) you can drop it from the `except` clause.

Comment: Thanks. I want `x` to be `None` if any of `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D `is `None`. Actually, I need `x = A.B.C.D or DEFAULT_VALUE`

Comment: Hey @Costin, thanks for the clarification. So you could go without the `NameError` but else leave the code as proposed (or change `None` in `x = None` to the default value that you want to have actually).

Answer (score 1):

I would define a function that allows you get the desired behavior in just one line:

```
def f(x, lst, default_val=None):
    for att in lst:
        if hasattr(x, attr):
            x = getattr(x, attr)
        else:
            return default_val
    return x
```

Now you can do things like this:

```
X = f(A, ['B', 'C', 'D'])
```

As suggested in the comments, if you don't need a default value, then you can just define the function as follows:

```
def f(x, lst):
    for att in lst:
        x = getattr(x, attr, None)
    return x
```

Comment: You can also remove completely the check of `hasattr` and simply use the `default` argument of [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to be `getattr(x, lst[i], None)`

Comment: And change the for loop to just loop over the elements instead of an index: `for attr in lst: x = getattr(x, attr, None)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo I would agree if the default value is always None. But the OP wants a custom default value. What if that value actually has the next attribute?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco A default value is not specified in the question and it's also not part of the JS syntax. A default is probably a different question altogether. But good on you for adding it anyway :-)

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, you're right. The part where the OP is asking for a custom default value can be found in the comments below another answer. It's not part of the original question. What do you guys suggest? Should I just answer the original question or also consider comments that can be found elsewhere?

Comment: Oh yes I just saw the other comment. I asked the OP to edit the question with it so your answer gets better context. Anyway, in that case I guess you are right with your approach :)

Answer (score -1):

I think a one-liner would be very messy here tbh. If you have `get` available for whatever these objects are you could do something like:

```
b = A.get(B, None) if A else None
c = B.get(C, None) if B else None
x = C.get(D, None) if C else None
```

Generally Python favours more lines of code to make something explicit rather than a complex one-liner.

Comment: How do you know `A`, `B`, `C` have a `get()` method?

Comment: I guess this solution works on dictionaries only. My objects do not have a `get` method. For dictionaries I use to use `d1.get('d2', {}).get('d3', {}).get('target')`

Comment: True, I don't know that, but if you're doing stuff like this I'd kind of expect to be using something that _did_ have a `get` implementation :)

Comment: Why? What do you mean *doing stuff like this*? Accessing attributes? Are you saying that all classes should have a `get` method? That already exists as the built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)...

Comment: I mean if this is a common use case for the OP, then use a structure that supports it is all. Wasn't trying to be argumentative - each to his own :) I made a suggestion - if it doesn't work for OP's case, no problem.